# Edit Moeda Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Preciso formatar um edit no formato `0,00` em *FireMonkey*, utilizando de preferência o evento `ChangeTracking`.
Tentei utilizar o seguinte procedimento que não resolveu.

```
procedure FormatadorMoeda(pEdit: TEdit);
var
  loStr: string;
  loDouble: double;
begin
  loStr := pEdit.Text;

  if loStr = EmptyStr then
    loStr := '0,00';

  loStr := Trim(StringReplace(loStr, '.', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]));
  loStr := Trim(StringReplace(loStr, ',', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]));

  loDouble := StrToFloat(loStr);
  loDouble := (loDouble / 100);
  pEdit.Text := FormatFloat('###,##0.00', loDouble);
  pEdit.SelStart := Length(pEdit.Text);
end;
```

Comment: Tente fazer no evento OnTyping do TEdit

Answer (score 4):

Segue o método para fazer a formatação:

```
function TForm1.DisplayFormatter(AValue: double; ADisplayFormar: String): String;
begin
  Result := FormatFloat(ADisplayFormar, AValue);
end;
```

Não aconselho a utilizar esse cara no `ChangeTracking`, o legal mesmo é você disparar esse método quando o cara terminar de preencher o campo.

Segue um exemplo de utilização:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iAux: Double;
begin
  if (Edit1.Text = EmptyStr) then
    Edit1.Text := '0';

  if TryStrToFloat(Edit1.Text, iAux) then
    Edit1.Text := DisplayFormatter(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text), ('#0.00'));
end;
```

Obs.: Poderia implementar um bloqueio de teclas no edit, se ele for "NumbersOnly"

Comment: Precisava que o comportamento do Edit fosso parecido com os campos de unidade monetária que são utilizados nos sites de bancos, formatação instantânea ao digitar.

Comment: nesse caso, você pode usar esse mesmo método no evento ChangeTracking do Edit

Answer (score 2):

Utilize no evento `onTyping` do Edit o trecho abaixo que vai resolver pra você:

```
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      txt, txt2: string;
      x: integer;
    begin
      txt := Edit1.Text;
      txt2 := '';
      for x := 0 to Length(txt) - 1 do
        if (txt.Chars[x] In ['0' .. '9']) then
          txt2 := txt2 + txt.Chars[x];

      txt := txt2;
      Edit1.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', StrToFloatDef(txt, 0) / 100);
      Edit1.GoToTextEnd;
    end);
```

Esse código pega o conteúdo digitado no edit, tira os pontos e as vírgulas (considerando teclado numérico), depois converte pro formato numérico de acordo com o idioma da plataforma, no caso brasileiro, o número de 4 dígitos e 2 decimais ficaria assim `1.234,56`

Answer (score -3):

```
TThread.Queue(nil,
procedure
var
  txt, txt2: string;
  x: integer;
begin
  txt := Edit1.Text;
  txt2 := '';
  for x := 0 to Length(txt) - 1 do
    if (txt.Chars[x] In ['0' .. '9']) then
      txt2 := txt2 + txt.Chars[x];

  txt := txt2;
  Edit1.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', StrToFloatDef(txt, 0) / 100);
  Edit1.GoToTextEnd;
end);
```

Maravilhoso! irmão vc deu ai algo que procuro a anos parabéns pela contribuição

Comment: O Stack Overflow é um [site de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387). [Não somos fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387) ou [rede social](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/137387). Esse espaço é exclusivo para publicar respostas a pergunta da página. Não use para [duplicar respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/485244/137387) ou fazer comentário ou agradecimentos.